# How to use 2 addEventListener inside 1 useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

[code react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad7Ye.png)

I want to make this code shorter, what is the best way to do it , using best practices.

Comment: Why not putting both of them in same useEffect ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [dims, setDims] = useState({})

useEffect(() => window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  setDims({height: window.innerHeight, width: window.innerWidth})
}))
```

P.S. Put your code in questions with text, not with an image